# Xm setup on SunFire X4200

Tags: virtual-machines, xen, sun

I'm trying to set a Xen VM on a SunFire X4200. I'm using Debian Wheezy and have followed this guide  https://wiki.debian.org/Xen which I used in previous attempts on different servers and worked without any problem. 
I know a different server of same model already hosts some xen VMs, so I can't understand why this is not working for me

```
xm create xxx.cfg
Using config file "/etc/xen/xxx.cfg".
Error: Creating domain failed: name=xxx
```

Here is my xxx.cfg:

```
# Configuration file for the Xen instance xxx, created
# by xen-tools 4.3.1 on Fri Jun 20 00:51:12 2014.
#

#     
#  Kernel + memory size
#
kernel      = '/boot/vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-amd64'
ramdisk     = '/boot/initrd.img-3.2.0-4-amd64'

vcpus       = '1'
memory      = '2048'

#
#  Disk device(s).
#
root        = '/dev/xvda2 ro'
disk        = [
              'phy:/dev/xen-vol/xxx-disk,xvda2,w',
              'phy/dev/xen-vol/xxx-swap,xvda1,w',
          ]


#
#  Physical volumes
#


# 
#  Hostname
#
name        = 'xxx'

#
#  Networking
#
dhcp        = 'dhcp'
vif         = [ 'mac=***,bridge=xenbr0' ]

#
#  Behaviour
on_poweroff = 'destroy'
on_reboot   = 'restart'
on_crash    = 'restart'
```

In the image creation log, everything seems to be ok, except for:

`mv: cannot stat '/tmp/Wtd9_3apX5/sbin/initctl': No such file or directory`

The xend.log reports an ERROR:

```
[2014-06-20 10:49:05 21306] ERROR (XendDomainInfo:2560) (1, 'Operation not permitted')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/xen-4.1/bin/../lib/python/xen/xend/XendDomainInfo.py", line 2555, in _constructDomain
    target = self.info.target())
Error: (1, 'Operation not permitted')

[2014-06-20 10:49:05 21306] ERROR (XendDomainInfo:488) VM start failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/xen-4.1/bin/../lib/python/xen/xend/XendDomainInfo.py", line 473, in start
    XendTask.log_progress(0, 30, self._constructDomain)
  File "/usr/lib/xen-4.1/bin/../lib/python/xen/xend/XendTask.py", line 209, in log_progress
    retval = func(*args, **kwds)
  File "/usr/lib/xen-4.1/bin/../lib/python/xen/xend/XendDomainInfo.py", line 2566, in _constructDomain
    raise VmError(failmsg)
VmError: Creating domain failed: name=xxx

[2014-06-20 10:49:05 21306] ERROR (XendDomainInfo:108) Domain construction failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/xen-4.1/bin/../lib/python/xen/xend/XendDomainInfo.py", line 106, in create
    vm.start()
  File "/usr/lib/xen-4.1/bin/../lib/python/xen/xend/XendDomainInfo.py", line 473, in start
    XendTask.log_progress(0, 30, self._constructDomain)
  File "/usr/lib/xen-4.1/bin/../lib/python/xen/xend/XendTask.py", line 209, in log_progress
    retval = func(*args, **kwd
  File "/usr/lib/xen-4.1/bin/../lib/python/xen/xend/XendDomainInfo.py", line 2566, in _constructDomain
    raise VmError(failmsg)
    VmError: Creating domain failed: name=xxx
```

Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turned out that AMD Opteron 254 is bugged and I had to remove security option in xen (found that by issuing xm dmesg after trying to create the VM)